# laravel 5 reletionship hasMany on two columns

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I'm trying to implement relationship on two columns, record_id and table_name,

here is what I got so far, Model name BatteryAssets:

```
public function Attachments()
    {
       return $this->hasMany('App\Attachments','record_id','id')->where('tabel_name','`battery_assets`');
    }
```

please note that 'battery_asstes' is a string, so it's not dynamic, I'm trying to make it as a string, but get the following error :

```
QueryException in Connection.php line 761:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'tabel_name' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `attachments` where `attachments`.`record_id` = 1 and `attachments`.`record_id` is not null and `tabel_name` = `battery_assets`)
```

as you see I'm I have tried to put battery_assets into `` and also I've tried to put them into double quotes ' "battery_assets" ' and also no quotes

and also please not that BatteryAssets table does not have table_name column, I'm only want to use it as a static value in the where clause, also I've tryied to do

```
->where('attachments.tabel_name','"battery_assets"');
```

but It gives the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says Colomn not found, the column name you are trying to 'call' is called 'tabel_name'. Are you sure the column name isn't 'table_name'? (table in english and not dutch, atleast I think you are dutch)

So it should be:

```
public function Attachments()
    {
       return $this->hasMany('App\Attachments','record_id','id')->where('table_name','`battery_assets`');
    }
```

If your column is called 'tabel_name' in your database. I would recommend using English naming, since 'name' is English.

Answer (score 1):

There was a typo, it all works now:

```
public function Attachments()
    {
       return $this->hasMany('App\Attachments','record_id','id')->where('table_name','battery_assets');
    }
```